# permission denied for all cd /mnt

Tags: permissions, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Ubuntu on Windows 10. I use `/mnt/` to access my file system and it worked normally before.

But after I changed the permissions of one of my folders to `700`, I started to get `permission denied` errors for all of `cd/mnt/` folders.

Comment: I edited your question and wasn't sure about your last folder. You wrote that it's `cd/mnt/`, but I suspect that it may be `/mnt`. I left it as it was, but if it's wrong, please correct it with an edit to the question.

Comment: Non-owners need at least execute permission in order to enter/traverse directories; typically the minimum useful permission mode for directories is `755`

Comment: i changed the permission of a folder under /mnt/g  using chmod -R 700 and after I did this cd/mnt does not work for any drive

Comment: You might find this YouTube video helpful. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=T269zebUSj8